# Is there a way to select an array in an array in a JSON response, without using standard number indexing (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

There is a subarray in a JSON response.

JSON Returned

```
{
“Id” : 12345,
“Name” :  “dads”,
Variants: [ 

    {“color” : “red”,
    “origin” :  “america”},

    {“color” : “blue”,
    “origin” :  “china”},

    {“color” : “yellow”,
    “origin” :  “mongolia”}
]
}
```

I am using Ajax to get a JSON reponse. The following is returned.
I have no idea of knowing the order of the ‘variants’. So I cannot use

```
data.variants[1].color
```

Is there a way to pull the variant where origin == blue.

```
$.getJSON('/url', function(data) {
   alert(data.variants[where origin==china].color);
});
```

Comment: You can use `Array.find()` for a single item, or `Array.filter()` for multiple items with the same origin.

Comment: `const result = data.Variants.find(v => v.color == "blue");` OR `const result = data.Variants.filter(v => v.color == "blue");`

Comment: @seamus I noticed you seem to write `where origin == blue`, but then you write china in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first matching object:

```js
let data = {
  "Id": 12345,
  "Name": "dads",
  "Variants": [{
    "color": "red",
    "origin": "america"
  }, {
    "color": "blue",
    "origin": "china"
  }, {
    "color": "yellow",
    "origin": "mongolia"
  }]
}

let result = data.Variants.find(v => v.origin === 'china')
console.log(result)
```

Documentation: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lamba expression. Specifically some kind of filter function will work for you if you want to get back a collection of items.

or Find for a specific element.

### Code (filter for multiple)

```
<script>

var a = {
"Id" : 12345,
"Name" :  "dads",
Variants: [ 

    {"color" : "red",
    "origin" :  "america"},

    {"color" : "blue",
    "origin" :  "china"},

    {"color" : "yellow",
    "origin" :  "mongolia"}
]
};

const result = a.Variants.filter(v => v.color == "blue");

console.log(result);



</script>
```

### Update

Or `const result = a.Variants.find(v => v.color == "blue");`

Obviously, if you're looking for `origin == china` , just change it to: `const result = a.Variants.find(v => v.origin== "china");`.

Find = one, filter = multiple

### SqlFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnsh2764/2

Comment: Or `const result = a.Variants.find(v => v.color == "blue");`

Comment: Obviously, if you're looking for `origin == china` , just change it to:
`const result = a.Variants.find(v => v.origin== "china"); `. Find = one, filter = multiple.